# Привязка элемента к камере в Unity

Tags: unity3d

В Unity нужно сделать так, чтобы джойстик был привязан к углу камеры и при передвижении персонажа оставался в углу, а не оставался на канвасе. Пробовал просто кинуть джойстик на камеру, не помогло.

Comment: Потому, что к камере ничего не прикрепляют. Аналог это `UI` элемент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй canvas, а именно UI, но еще проще скачай джойстик в Assets store, вот есть бесплатный:

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/joystick-pack-107631

Если хочешь, то можешь поменять спрайты.